# paper-menu-button's dropdown has scrollbars?

Tags: polymer

i am working with paper-menu-button and when i add content to the menu i get scroll bars showing up. i have 2 questions

1. anyone have any idea how i can correct this?
2. where would i add a paper-shadow to have it show up under the menu not under the button.

including a image below along with my menu's code.

[image]

```
      <paper-menu-button icon="more-vert">
        <paper-item id="edit" icon="create" label="Edit"></paper-item>
        <paper-item id="delete" icon="remove-circle" label="Delete"></paper-item>
      </paper-menu-button>
```

Comment: disappointment i thought for sure someone could help me with this. i have removed the package from the bower folder and ran bower again. also tried downloading the package from the components page and deleting all the matching folders under the bower folder and coping fresh from the package. also having same issue on another unrelated page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbars look like a bug. You can temporarily correct it applying the following CSS:

```css
body /deep/ core-menu {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you.. that fixes it. as for the shadow i found that i had the button set with position absolute and to render the shadow it needs to be position relavent.

Comment: this fixes it in chrome for me, but doesn't in firefox 31

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty mimicking the shadowing around the dropdown menu as is shown on the paper-menu-button demo:

[Polymer paper-menu-button demo](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-menu-button/demo.html)

Any idea what property/attribute or CSS styling enables this?  You mentioned ensuring that the  menu-button has position: relative, but this didn't work for me (its already relative).

Here is a stripped down portion of the code, as requested.  Note I have elected not to use paper-shadow for the container:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
    <style>

        myContainer {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-right: 25px;
            padding-left: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
            /* z-index: -1; */
        }

        myHeading {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            /*padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;*/
            border-top-left-radius: 5px;
            border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
            text-align: center;
            background-color: lightgrey;
            color: black;
            font-weight: 700;
            /* z-index: -1; */
        }

    </style>

    <!--paper-shadow></paper-shadow-->

    <core-selector id="mySelector" target="{{$.myContainers}}" multi="false" selected="{{selectedContainer}}" selectedAttribute="active"></core-selector>

    <div id="myContainers" horizontal layout wrap>

        <div>
            <myHeading name="Container 1" horizontal layout center>
                <div flex>Container 1</div>
                <paper-menu-button icon="more-vert" halign="right">
                    <paper-item label="Edit" on-tap="{{ editItem }}"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item label="Copy"></paper-item>
                </paper-menu-button>
            </myHeading>
            <myContainer vertical layout>
                Container contents here
            </myContainer>
        </div>
```

Comment: maybe show us a piece of your css to get a better idea what you have atm. in my situation i placed the button inside a div container and positioned it with position:absolute then removed the position attribute from the paper-menu-button and the shadow worked.

Comment: i personally don't see anything in your css that would keep the shadow from rendering. maybe try putting the menu-button in a div container by it's self with no css attributes and see if it renders then. im not sure what exactly the "horizontal layout center" does in css. just a shot in the dark and i might be totally wrong.

Comment: Updated paper-menu-dropdown to latest version via bower and the problem with lack of shadowing disappeared